# to pass values (data) from our application to native app in android?

Tags: java, android

i am developing program for union and intersection of two strings in android, i also calculate number of character in union as well intersect results individually?the results values (union&intersect) should pass to native calculator and the result will shown in calculator?

i have to pass the that result data to native calculator?

examle:i have two strings

> sunday,
>   monday

the union is:**sundaymo**,the length of result **union** string is:**8**
 the intersection  is :**nday**,the length of result intersection string is:**4**

the sum of **union and intersection** is :**8+4=12**;
  the values 8 and 4 should pass to **native calculator**,the result should be shown in **native**    **calculator**.

how should i do please provide code for me 
please answer to me

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1 = new String("10201");
String s2 = new String("01341");


//intersect
HashSet<Character> h1 = new HashSet<Character>(), h2 = new HashSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)                                            
{
    h1.add(s1.charAt(i));
}
for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
{
    h2.add(s2.charAt(i));
}

//union
h1.addAll(h2);

//intersect
h1.retainAll(h2);


//
```